# Simple PHP saveHTML on specific element returns NULL

Tags: php, wordpress, dom, xpath, domdocument

The goal is to extract an element from a locally stored html file and insert it into the current page at the point when the php script is executed. This has been my first major PHP project so I expect the issue is simple (and I apologise for any non-technical language), but, as you will see, I cannot resolve it.

My code looks like this:

```
<?php 
    $path = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bglibrary/background.html";
    $html = new DOMDocument();
    $html->loadHtmlFile($path);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath ( $html );
    $background = $xpath->query("//*[@id='background-wrapper']");


    var_dump($background); // object(DOMNodeList)#307 (0) { } 
    var_dump($background->item(0)); // object(DOMElement)#306 (0) { }
    var_dump($background->item(1)); // NULL

    var_dump($html->saveHTML($background)); // NULL
    var_dump($html->saveHTML($background->item(0))); // NULL


    echo $html->saveHTML(); //Prints full html of the target page
?>
```

The var_dump commands are to debug, and they illustrate the problem. The x-path query is succeeding I think, because it returns a list of nodes with one item only (querying the second item on the list returns NULL). Furthermore, the item itself is identified as a dom element.

**However I have not been able to use `saveHTML` in any form** (including finding the target node's parent and then finding the element inside it to try and save it), or `saveXML`, or `saveHTMLfile`, to return, echo, print or dump the desired element. I have also tried using the `getElementById` php function with the exact same results.

In case it's a factor, my html (which is very simple also) follows;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Holding File for Images</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    ... some styling
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="background-wrapper">
        <div id="background1" dataalt="no" class="background">
        ...A whole load of div elements
        </div>

        <div id="background2" class="background">
        ...A whole load of div elements
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And finally, just in case you were thinking that the html file isn't being accessed properly somehow, that final `echo $html->saveHTML();` from my php does successfully output the entire html file I just listed, and it renders nicely.

---

An extremely similar question was asked this year by [remyable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18135342/savehtml-when-passed-node-returns-null) and received no answer apart from that the code seemed to run ok according to another user. I can assure you, this code and no similar variation seems to run ok, therefore I suspect the issue may lie in my server setup. I'm executing the PHP inside the header.php file of a wordpress site, which is hosted locally using MAMP to run. The MAMP server root is not the 'wordpress' file (since I'm working on some non-wordpress stuff too), hence why I use the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` command to find my html file. The file paths relevant to this case are:

root/wordpress/wp-content/themes/FirstTheme/header.php (where the php is being executed)

root/bglibrary/background.html (where the target HTML file is)

Comment: I just tried switching to 5.4 and now it works, do you want to post that as the answer?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php 5.3.6  The node parameter was added.

Comment: Do you want to post that as the answer?

Comment: ok, even with solution for 5.2 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

argument to [saveHTML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php) function was added only in php 5.3.6

so, you either need to install new version of php to use this or try [C14N](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.c14n.php) method which exists from 5.2.0:

`echo $background->item(0)->C14N();`

Comment: The C14N method works perfectly, and changing the version of PHP in MAMP to 5.4.10 gets the saveHTML to work too. However one thing still bugs me, 'echo $html->saveHTML($background->item(0))' is still producing the entire HTML page, including the doctype declaration and header- is this expected, is the C14N method the only way to avoid it?

Comment: @OlivierButler if it provides full html - then it is old version of php, it displays HTML of whole $html object, not just 1 node, I'm testing on php 5.5 and both methods works the same